# Search form expand text area to 100% and adjust search button to appear next to it

Tags: css

I want to expand the search area to the full width (100%) of the page but retain the search button still next to it. No matter how I adjust the float, the search button can never appear next to the input text field when the width is 100%.

```html
<div class="container-inline">
  <h2 class="element-invisible">Search form</h2>
  <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-search-block-form">
    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-search-block-form--2">Search</label>
    <input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." type="search" id="edit-search-block-form--2" name="search_block_form" value="" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
    <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Search" class="form-submit">
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-4z8ikoOcVIhJ_RSkgpUyI989ZS6XhJQN4VRPZbs3Apw">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="AmbnEOBFHg5XAQV2KWD4hH_O1Y3aQYwS8tLycR_vCZs">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="search_block_form">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little different approach... `label`, `search` and `button` have they own containers (`divs`).

In this example I put one more `div`, some kind of container for those 3, and for `display` use `table` (for container) and `table-cell` (for those 3 divs).

```css
.container
{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

.divLabel, .divSearch, #edit-actions
{
display:table-cell;
}
.divSearch {width:100%; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;}
#edit-search-block-form--2 {width:100%; box-sizing:border-box;}
```

```html
<div class="container-inline">
  <h2 class="element-invisible">Search form</h2>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="divLabel">
    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-search-block-form--2">Search</label>
    </div>
    <div class="divSearch">
    <input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." type="search" id="edit-search-block-form--2" name="search_block_form" value="" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
    <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Search" class="form-submit">
  </div>
        </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-4z8ikoOcVIhJ_RSkgpUyI989ZS6XhJQN4VRPZbs3Apw">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="AmbnEOBFHg5XAQV2KWD4hH_O1Y3aQYwS8tLycR_vCZs">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="search_block_form">
</div>
```

I hope so this is what You need.

Comment: Worked great! Didn't think that a table display can work for divs. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Michael You're welcome.... `flex` is also very interested, You can see here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/